# How to fix desktop reloading during logout/shutdown/restart after upgrading to 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, shutdown, restart, logout

Since I've upgraded my system to Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot), I'm facing a strange problem each time I logout/shutdown/restart :

1. As usual, Unity's launcher, global menu, desktop items and desktop are unloaded ;
2. Screen flickers ;
3. Desktop items are reloaded but at another position (I suppose because there is no launcher) with ClearLooks theme [please note I'm using Ambiance theme] ;
4. Sometimes I'm also asked to provide the password to unlock the keyring [each time I get this window, my desktop items are ones over the others at next logon] ;
5. After about 25 seconds, the logout/shutdown/restart continues without problem.

I'm sure this is due to some parameters in my user profile, because if I create a new user I don't have the problem at all.

For information, I've already tried to reset gnome by removing .gnome, .gnome2, .gconf, .gconfd, .metacity. I've also removed compiz configuration and nautilus configuration as well as doing some cleanup in .config (dconf, ...) and .local (applications, mime, ...).

I'm very interested in finding the culprit, but I don't know anywhere else I can search in user home folder...

Any advice will be very appreciated!

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found what is going wrong on my system.
If I close properly Tomboy by using "Quit" before logout/shutdown/restart, everything works fine (no desktop reloading and no need to wait 25 seconds more).

For information, Tomboy is launched at startup on my session.

Even if the symptoms are not exactly the same and I'm using the 32-bit edition of Ubuntu 11.10, it might be linked to this bug : [816950](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dbus-sharp/+bug/816950)

A bug has now been opened for this problem : [880299](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/880299)

I'm going to try to reproduce the problem on a fresh install...